# How to create new Farm in Share Point 2010 on single server?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-server, server-farm, sharepoint-farm

I want to create new Farm on Share Point 2010 server. I have already one Farm on same SharePoint 2010 server and want to create new Farm with existing Farm on same server. 
That means I require multiple farm working on same SharePoint 2010 server. 
Is it possible to create new Farm? Please provide step to create new Farm if possible to create.

Comment: I want to create multiple farm on my Share Point 2010 system. Please help me.

Comment: Why don't you try with Virtual Machine?

Comment: I am already using VM for it, but I want 2 different farms working together. So I can configure both farm different way on single server.

Answer (score 0):

You can not have two SharePoint farm on one server, Main reason is Config DB. One Server can connect to one Configuration Database only. You can Share the SQL Server between multiple farms.

Your Best bet is create another VM and configured the 2nd farm.

Comment: Tank you for reply. http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2131832&seqNum=2  but given articles says that this is possible and I found from others sources that multiple farm is possible but I don't find steps for that.

Comment: did you try with new SQL instance for new farm then we can avoid conflicts.